# How can i show a site in my web application?

Tags: asp.net

in my web application i have a button controls like yahoo button, gmail button etc.,
 when i click on any button i want to show the related site in my web application (i want to show the site in a particular part of my web application) right side corner of my web application how can i show the site, which control i have to use.
in window application we have webBrowser control in web application how can i show the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iframe](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.5) (although some site authors object to having their content embedded in other sites and implement frame bursting techniques)

Comment: MR. David It is not working in IE6, it is working in fire fox

Comment: IE6 has no problems with the iframe element. That problem must lie with your specific implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iframe. When a button is clicked you set its `src` property to the respective site:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: Mr. Darin Dimitrov it is not working in IE 6, but it is working in firefox

Answer (score 0):

You ca use an iframe and load the website within your page. Just set the src attribute for the iframe.